# Adjusting row height according to text in selected column in excel

Tags: java, html, css, excel

Hi I am generating report in excel through java code. I set height of rows and width of columns, but in some column the data is too large that affect the height of other columns

```
$25.000.000 APROXIMADO MENSUAL DE LOS               Referencia Transportador    
TRES VEHICULOS - CARGA PESADA - PAGO              
FLETES POR CONTRATO DE ENCARGO 
A TERCEROS
```

the above lines effect the height "Referencia Transportador" column.

Answer (score 0):

Highlight all of the rows that you want to change the height of > right click > select "Row Height..." (fyi, ".21" is the default for excel) > then every row should be that size, regardless of the size of the content.

You might also have "wrap text" on. Depending on which Microsoft Office you have, turning this on and off varies. A quick search on Google or in the help documentation should help you figure that out.